# Python Column Duplicate Checker

Tags: python

```
file = input("Enter a filename: ")
fi = open(file, "r")
for line in fi:
    line = line.split()
    c = len(line)
    print(line)
    print (c)


def anydup(line): # Checks for duplicates in the rows
    seen = set()
    for x in line:
        if x in seen:print("There are some duplicate numbers in the rows") 
        seen.add(x)
        print("There are no duplicates in the rows")
```

Can someone please tell me how to check for duplicates in column of numbers, i've already found out how to found duplicates in rows. This is for a sudoku grid 9x9. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `seen` set for each row and each column, for 18 total. Then each number you read, check for membership in the row's `seen` and the column's `seen`.

Comment: could you please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best approach in terms of efficiency, but it's pretty straight forward to understand.  I think with a 9x9 grid, understandability is more important than speed.

You have a matrix where row operations are easy, so let's just transpose it. When our rows become our columns, we can use the anydup_row function again.

I'm going to assume the lines are all complete and that your data in the file is separated by spaces.

```
infile = input("Enter a filename: ") #Don't use python builtins for names!
fi = open(infile, "r")
matrix = map(lambda x: x.split(), fi.readlines())

def anydup_row(matrix): # Checks for duplicates in the rows
    dupes = [False] * 9
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        if len(set(row)) < 9:
            dupes[i] = True
    return dupes

def anydup_columns(matrix):
    matrix_T = zip(*matrix)
    return anydup_row(matrix_T)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to check for duplicates. Obviously it doesn't also make sure entries are 1-9, but that seems to be taken for granted.

```
fi = input("Enter a filename: ")

grid = [line.split() for line in open(fi)]

for row in grid:
    assert len(set(row)) == 9

for col in range(9):
    assert len(set(row[col] for row in grid)) == 9
```

Comment: May have to use raw_input for older versions of python, or rely on user to put quotes around the input filename.